# ReactJS browserCheck function implementation to an existing app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `browserCheck` function which returns boolean value (for example, `false` if IE version is less than 10). Somehow I need to implement it to an existing ReactJS app and inject placeholder into page if the result of the function will be `false`. I can not clearly understand how to do it.

The project structure looks like this:

```
|--project
 |--src
  |--browserCheck
     ----browserCheck.js 
     ----incompatible.html (an error message in case browserCheck() returns `false`)
  ----app.jsx (which contains the whole app and its imports)
  ----index.js (where the ReactDOM.render happens; dependencies - React, ReactDOM, App)
```

Where should I run the function and replace the content?

---

I tried to console.log the result of `browserCheck()` in the index.js file, and it's returns `true`if i run the app in modern browsers, but if I use it in IE<10 I just see white screen and the function returns nothing.

---

`console.log` content when i get the white screen:
[image: <code>console.log</code> content when i get the white screen]

---

`index.js` content:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import 'normalize.css';
import './index.css';

import browserCheck from './browserCheck/browserCheck'

console.log( browserCheck() );

ReactDOM.render( < App / > ,
 document.getElementById( 'root' )
);
```

Comment: Could you include the index file where you are calling `browserCheck` in the question?

Comment: Can you tell us the console logs (if any) that you get on the white screen?

Comment: @Tholle I uptaded my question whith the required information.

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta I uptaded my question whith the required information.

Comment: It might be that `browserCheck()` works, but that the IE console isn't logging when there are other errors. Try wrapping your `ReactDOM.render` in a `browserCheck `.  `if (browserCheck()) { ReactDOM.render(...);  }`